# Unable to run my test in Karate framework

Tags: java, cucumber, karate, cucumber-java

I have configured karate with eclipse. When I run this, only first test gets executed. It does not execute the 2nd test automatically. I suspect my run configurations of cucumber are only displaying the first feature file. What can I do?

If I run this with JUnit, it says

> 3:58:18.819 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate.core.FeatureParser - not a valid feature file: secondtest.feature - mismatched input 'A' expecting <EOF>

[image]

Comment: totally agree with comment above, please improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a fresh project:  https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/IDE-Support - and a fresh Eclipse Workspace.

Also make sure the project runs via Maven on the command-line, e.g. `mvn test`. If it does, then you need to focus on troubleshooting your Eclipse environment.

As Karate is an open-source project, contributions to making Eclipse support are welcome. A lot of teams use IntelliJ and Visual Studio Code.

Comment: when I tried to run my tests with mvn test, I get error initialization error Test Runner. mismatched input A expecting eof.

Comment: @RazaSohail maybe you really have a feature with a syntax error. follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue